# Cheating throughout university

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, islamic-scholar, cheating

My circumstances are a little specific.

I would like to ask if I should quit university in order to attain halal income instead.

It has been about 5 years since I started university, I have more or less have been cheating in all of my major courses. Only in recent months have I come to the conclusion that if I were to find a degree in my major, the money earned from it would perhaps be haram due to the way I would get my bachelor's degree.

So my question is, should I stay in school or drop out?

I feel that on the day of resurrection, I will be asked about this.

Comment: Let us know something to know your case more specifically. What kind of cheating was that!!

Comment: We do not give personal advice. Cheating is haram, however the money you earn from a job after graduation may not be haram just because of this.

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/355567/ruling-on-certificate-and-earnings-if-one-cheated-on-exams